# Text will not populate in React Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create 4 react panels using Grid to showcase my skills for my Portfolio application. My text was working fine but, once I tried to implement a custom Paper Grid from material UI the text is being overridden somehow and I'm not sure why.
Here is my code where I declare the custom Grid:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    color:'green',
  },
  paper: {
    height: 150,
    width: 100
  },


}));

const SpacingGrid = () => {
  const [spacing] = React.useState(2);
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <theme>
      <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Grid container justify="center" spacing={spacing}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Paper className={classes.control}>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item></Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </theme>
  );
};

export default SpacingGrid;
```

Here is my code where I call the Grid and use it to implement my skills:

```
import React from 'react'
import Panel from '../accessories/Panels'
import SpacingGrid from '../accessories/Grid'

const frontEnd =['Django','Reactjs','Javascript','HTML','CSS']
const backEnd =['Python','Typescript','Nodejs','Express']
const databases =['MongoDB','MySQL']
const tools = ['AWS','AWS-CDK','Docker','AWS-Lambda','Figma','Microservices','Kubernetes']


//I should probably make my own styled components for this but NEED to learn how

const Skills = () =>{
    return(
        <div>
        <h1 color="whitePrimary" align="center">
            Skills
        </h1>
        <SpacingGrid>
        <Panel flexWidth="25" padding="1" rounded>
        <h1 color="whitePrimary" align="center">
            Front-End
        </h1>
        <p color="whitePrimary" align="center">
        </p>
        {frontEnd.map((item) =>(
            <p color="textPrimary" align="center" key={item}>
                {item}
            </p>
        ))}

        </Panel>
        <Panel flexWidth="31" padding="1" rounded>
            <h1 color="whitePrimary" align="center">
                Back-End
            </h1>
            <p color="whitePrimary" align="center">

            </p>
            {backEnd.map((item) => (
                <p color="textPrimary" align="center" key={item}>
                    {item}
                </p>

            ))}
        </Panel>
        <Panel flexWidth="31" padding="1" rounded>
            <h1 color="whitePrimary" align="center">
                Databases:

            </h1>
            <p color="whitePrimary" align="center">
            </p>
            {databases.map(((item) =>(
                <p color="textPrimary" align="center" key={item}>
                    {item}

                </p>

            )))}
        </Panel>
    
        <Panel flexWidth="31" padding="1" rounded>
            <h1 color="whitePrimary" align="center">
                General Tooling:
            </h1>
            <p color="whitePrimary" align="center">
            </p>
            {tools.map((item => (
                <p color="textPrimary" align="center" key={item}>
                    {item}
                    
                </p>
                )))}
        </Panel>
        </SpacingGrid>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Skills;
```

Here is my App.js my file were all the components sit:

```
import {React, Suspense} from 'react'
import SocialFooter from '../components/SocialMediaFooter'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Skills from '../components/SkillsPanels'


const Main = () =>{

return(
    <div>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Header />

    
    </Suspense>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Skills />
    </Suspense>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading... </div>}>
        <SocialFooter />
    </Suspense>
    </div>

)}



    //add all react components here and export to app.js


export default Main;
```

My issue is that I believe the error to be in the Grid.js file. Now the code works but, it does not add the text to the app as I have it in SkillsPanels.js it just gives me blank Grids which leaves me stumped. Thank you all!

Comment: Did you mean to render `props.children` or similar somewhere in `SpacingGrid`? It looks to be wrapping `Panel` in `Skills`, but nothing in `SpacingGrid`, unless i'm missing somewhere would render the passed children.

Comment: This was exactly the answer I did not understand how to use props.children yet. So I passed props to the function and called props.children in the container and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I passed props in the SpacingGrid function and then called {props.children} next to